# Facebook Insights API Pagination

Tags: facebook, facebook-insights

There is no content on the FB Insights API documentation about how to work with the pagination cursors that come back with responses. Any idea of how to query for the next set of data and track whether I have received all data?

Edited:
An example request may look like:

```
curl -G -d "date_preset=this_year" -d "level=campaign" -d 
"access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN" 
"https://graph.facebook.com/v3.3/act_10154799731395544/insights"
```

And the response will be something to the effect of:

```
{"data":[DATA],"paging":{"cursors":{"before":"MAZDZD","after":"MTAZD"}}}
```

How can I then utilize the before and after cursors to iterate through further results?

Comment: please include an example request with cursors. in general, the pagination includes the api call for the next set already.

Comment: See edits in the original question.

Comment: this does not look like there is more data...usually, there is a "next" link in the paging object.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api#paging If there really is no previous / next URLs given in the response, you can create them yourself by appending the cursor parameters manually.

Comment: Got it; so I would need to iterate continuously using the 'after' cursor until a response came back with no data or no 'after' cursor?